# Old used electronics, can I re-use them for other purposes?

Tags: camera, board

I have taken apart and had a look at a small dashboard camera which was broken due to the solders on the button going loose and detaching. Upon inspection, I could turn the camera on without it's casing however the screen would just turn white and nothing would happen.

I want to use this as a SD card reader since I don't think I will get the camera to work, the problem is that whenever I try to access the SD card it crashes my explorer due to incorrect drivers. Is there anyway I can make this work or should I just throw this junk away?

Idea of what the situation looks like:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's *possible* to make this work, but I would throw it away. Buying a new SD card reader is a simpler, cheaper, faster, easier, more reliable solution. Do you really want to reverse engineer that board and spend hours and hours diagnosing and defining the problem? (I wouldn't, but that's just me. I'm sure some people would love this challenge.) That's not even considering the added complexity of the driver issue. You would certainly learn a lot about this technology and the equipment/computer interfaces if you got it to work. You could also learn a lot about other things in the time that you save *not* fixing it.